# Visualization of an Order Verified by Wilcoxon

Tags: visualization

**The background:** After I've conducted a survey about preferences of users in ridesharing, I now want to construct an order of importance of these preferences (this is to answer one of my research questions). For instance *price* might be more important than *comfort of the vehicle* might be more important than *the played music*. I collected the data based on a five-point likert-scale.

**My procedure so far:**

1. Of course clearing the data
2. Generate an order via a simple approach: *very important* gets $4$, *important* gets $3$ and so on. Then I build a sum over all answers and I sort the preferences based on their sums.

The second step provides me with an order, which is not statistically verified. Therefore,

3. I perform a one-sided Wilcoxon signed-rank test for each pair of preferences.

The resulting p-values are in the following matrix:

[image]

The visualization can be read as follows: preference *a* is statistically proven to be not less important than preference *d* to *j* for all common significance levels. (The order of preferences comes from the second step.)

The **problem** is, I've collected $42$ preferences and the corresponding visualization has the following problems:

- $42$ is quite a lot and the visualization gets confusing.
- Moreover, to understand what is shown in the graphic a lot of brain work is needed, especially for an unexperienced user.

**Do you have an idea how to visualize the result better?**

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a good way to answer your question since I do not know who your audience is, what actions/understandings are you trying to drive from your analysis, etc.

I think that is where you need to start. If your audience is executives in charge of revenue, perhaps showing the difference in revenue where the top n preferences are in a car vs n-1, n-2, ....  Or frequency of the top preferences.

Given the audience and the action/understanding you may not need to show all 42 preferences in the mainline of your presentation.

You can also look for inspiration on your audience/action from traditional statistical methods for this type of analysis.  Namely [conjoint](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjoint_analysis) part of [choice modeling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_modelling). Take a look at some of those public analysis or classes and maybe an idea will take hold that is similar to your audience/action.

This is more of a path forward rather than an answer but I do not see the question as answerable right now.

Comment: I'm doing research, so in the audience are mostly other researchers. By the way: I did not use a conjoint analysis in the first place because there are also other research objectives. Because I cannot simply conduct a second survey with a feasible number of participants, I have to use my current data.